# Forcing UK date Format Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, date

All I have the below code which essentially formats Col J:J of the transaction lines. To DD-MM-YY however the date format is appearing as MM-DD-YY American format is there a better way to ensure it is always DD-MM-YY

```
Sub Formatdate()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim sPath As String, sFile As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wbname As String
wbname = "Transactions.csv"
sPath = "\\Csdatg04\psproject\Robot\Project Preload\Transactions\Robot WIP\"
sFile = sPath & "Transactions.csv"
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFile)


Workbooks(wbname).Worksheets(1).Range("J:J").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "DD-MM-YYYY"
Workbooks(wbname).Close True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True



End Sub
```

Comment: Have your source dates in format yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: If your region is UK, specify the `Local:=True` argument when opening the file.

Comment: @Rory thanks rory, I open the file using the below code; Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(FFile) where would local:=true fit into this?

Comment: Like this: `Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(filename:=FFile, local:=true)`